# Lodash move objects under a key part of same object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an JSON object like

```
datas = [ 
    {"id":1,"name":"Test","age":24}, 
    {"id":2,"name":"Test1","age": 30}
]
```

I want to modify the JSON object like below

```
datas = [ 
        {"1":{"name":"Test","age":24}}, 
        {"2":{"name":"Test1","age": 30}}
    ]
```

I want to do the same using `lodash` . I can understand `map` over the `data` and create a new object should fix this

```
updated_data=[]
_.map datas, (data) ->
  Obj = {}
  Obj[data.id] = data
  updated_data.push(Obj)
```

But I am looking for `lodash` way of achieving the same .

Comment: Explore this https://lodash.com/docs/#keyBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` (or `_.map()`) with destructuring and object rest (`...`):

```js
const datas = [{"id":1,"name":"Test","age":24}, {"id":2,"name":"Test1","age": 30}]

const result = datas.map(({ id, ...o }) => ({ [id]: o }))

console.log(result)
```

With lodash you can do the same, but instead of destructuring use `_.omit()` to remove the `id` from the original object, and use `_.zipObject()` combine it with the `id`:

```js
const datas = [{"id":1,"name":"Test","age":24}, {"id":2,"name":"Test1","age": 30}]

const result = _.map(datas, o => _.zipObject([o.id], [ _.omit(o, 'id')]))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I was actually looking for solution using `lodash` only since I am using `coffescript` and the `splats` `rest` is little tricky to implement there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use an extra library for this. This way you can achieve the desired result:

```js
datas.map((item) => {
  const { id, ...rest } = item;
  return {
    id: rest,
  };
});
```